# Como hacer que suba al principio de la pagina,con un paginador ? ngx-pagination - npm

Tags: bootstrap, angular, npm

he realizado un paginador mediante **ngx-pagination - npm**, el problema es que al pasar de pagina no sube arriba del todo y resulta muy incomodo.

Por favor ayuda, estoy seguro que sera alguna tontería.

**HTML**

```
<article  *ngFor="let post of posts | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }">

<pagination-controls 
    class = "my-pagination"
    (pageChange)="p = $event"
    previousLabel="Anterior"
    nextLabel="Siguiente"
    autoHide = "true"
    >
</pagination-controls>
```

Comment: Al momento de ejecutar el evento del atributo `pageChange` puedes agregar `window.scrollTo(0, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así

```html
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)"></pagination-controls>
```

Y este seria el evento `onPageChange`

```
onPageChange(page: number) {
   this.currentPage = page;
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

[Fuente](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/issues/266)

Answer (score 0):

> <pagination-controls class="my-pagination" previousLabel="Anterior"
> nextLabel="Siguiente" (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)"
> class="text-center">

onPageChange(page: number) { this.p = page; window.scrollTo(0, 0); }

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para agregar lo que pusiste en tu comentario _en_ la respuesta. Dale formato anteponiendo 4 espacios a cada línea de código, o ponlo entre ```. Además, explica brevemente qué hace el código: lee [answer].